# Probability of observing at least $k$ heads if coins have different probabilities of heads?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a collection of Bernoulli RVs $\{X_1, \ldots, X_N\}$ and know the success probabilities of each: $\{p_1, \ldots, p_N\}$.

Is there, in general, a way to efficiently compute the probability of observing at least $K$ successes without enumerating possible outcomes?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3346871/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the random variables $\ X_1, X_2, \dots, X_N\ $ are independent, then the probability mass functions, $\ \Pi_k\ $ of $\ \sum_\limits{i=1}^k X_i\ $ for $\ k=2,3,\dots,N\ $ can be computed iteratively by convolving that of $\ X_k\ $ with $\ \Pi_{k-1}\ $. The probability of at least $\ K\ $ successes can then be calculated as $\ \sum_\limits{i=K}^N\Pi_N(i)\ $.

Since the probability mass function of $\ X_k\ $ has just two atoms, $\ 0\ $, with probability $\ 1-p_k\ $, and $\ 1\ $, with probability $\ p_k\ $, its convolution with $\ \Pi_{k-1}\ $ is just the sum of $\ 1-p_k\ $ times $\ \Pi_{k-1}\ $ and $\ p_k\ $ times the "left shift" of $\ \Pi_{k-1}\ $.  More precisely,
\begin{align}
\Pi_k(j)&=\\
&\cases{\left(1-p_k\right)\Pi_{k-1}(0)& if $\ j=0\ $,\\
\left(1-p_k\right)\Pi_{k-1}(j)+p_k \Pi_{k-1}(j-1)& for $\ j=1,2,\dots,k\ $, or\\
0& if $\ j>k\ $.}
\end{align}
For arbitrary unstructured values of $\ p_1, p_2,\dots, p_N\ $, I doubt there'll be any more efficient way of calculating the probability of $\ K\ $ or more successes.